# Sorting an array which is based on a structure

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an array `s()` shown as below, I want to sort the array based on the values `s().Mean`, either highest to lowest or vice versa. I'm pretty new to VB.NET so interested in any solutions. I copied all the mean values to a simple array and tried to do `Array.Sort(s,Compare)` but get an `ICompare` error message so am now a bit (lot) lost on what to do next.

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Structure Values

        Public DateTime As String
        Public Value As Double

    End Structure

    Public Structure QDAS

        Public Index As Integer
        Public ID As String
        Public Description As String
        Public PartType As String
        Public Operation As String
        Public Status As Boolean
        Public Mean As Double
        Public Nominal As Double
        Public USL As Double
        Public LSL As Double
        Public Deviation As Double
        Public ErrorAfterTol As Double
        Public Max As Double
        Public Min As Double
        Public Range As Double
        Public TotalTolerance As Double
        Public PercentOfTol As Double
        Public Repeatability As Double
        Public Units As String
        Public Values() As Values


    End Structure

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim s(5) As QDAS

        Dim i

        For i = 0 To 5

            s(i).Description = "F" & i
            ReDim Preserve s(i).Values(5)

            For j = 0 To 5
                s(i).Values(j).Value = Rnd()
            Next

            For j = 0 To UBound(s(i).Values)
                s(i).Mean = s(i).Mean + s(i).Values(j).Value
            Next

            s(i).Mean = s(i).Mean / (UBound(s(i).Values) + 1)

        Next


        MsgBox("Done")

        Dim Compare() As Double = Nothing

        ReDim Compare(UBound(s))

        For i = 0 To UBound(s)

            Compare(i) = s(i).Mean
        Next

        Array.Sort(s, Compare)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The overload of [`Array.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_) that you're using assumes the first argument is the array of keys that you're sorting by, and the second argument is the array of values that you want to sort.

Just reverse the arguments:

```
' Sort low-to-high
Array.Sort(Compare, s)
```

Or

```
' Sort high-to-low
For i = 0 To UBound(s)
    Compare(i) = -s(i).Mean
Next
Array.Sort(Compare, s)
```

If you're comfortable with more advanced topics like [Object Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/object-initializers-named-and-anonymous-types), [Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions), and [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq), you can simplify your `Button1_Click` handler to this:

```
Dim CreateQDAS As Func(Of Integer, QDAS) = _
    Function (i As Integer) New QDAS With {
        .Values = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(Function (j) New Values With { .Value = Rnd() }).ToArray(),
        .Mean = .Values.Average(Function (v) v.Value)
    }

Dim s = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(CreateQDAS)
' Sort low-to-high
Dim Sorted = s.OrderBy(Function (item) item.Mean)
```

Or

```
' Sort high-to-low
Dim Sorted = s.OrderByDescending(Function (item) item.Mean)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat, must remember to read the manual!

Comment: @KeithMorton FYI, I've provided another solution using some of VB.NET's more advanced features. Given that you're still learning the language I'd recommend making sure you fully understand these features before you start using them, but I think the example is useful for demonstration purposes.